# SSIS - Composite characters

Tags: ssis

I have a flat file and one of the column in the flat file has composite characters and In the Flat File connection manager I defined that particular column as

**DataType - DT_WSTR**

**OutputColumnWidth - 40**

The actual column length in text file is 30 but as this has composite keys I increased it to 40. Now I placed a Dataviewer after the Flat File Source to see how the data is passed and I see different values For example *Société* is passed as *SociÃ©tÃ©*

Kindly help me to prevent this character conversion.

Please let me know if you need additional details. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed the code page on the Flat File connection manager to UTF-8 and it solved the issue :).

Comment: Thanks for posting your solution, I hope it helps the next person.

Comment: Thank you for posting this, It helped with my issue handling survey free text values given to me in xml form.